# Add posts category in CMB2 options

Tags: php, wordpress

I need to add a specific type of posts in a dropdown option to my CMB2 WordPress plugin. I have found where in my code my fields are generated; however, I see `taxonomies` being used as filters, but I would need a post `post_type`.

**Working, with taxonomies**

```
$cmb_events->add_field( array (
    'name'      => __('Catégorie d\'événement','aqmat'),
    'id'        => $prefix . 'categorie',
    'type'      => 'taxonomy_select',
    'taxonomy'  => 'aqmat_categorie_evenement'
));
```

I figured I'd query my posts to get only those I want and add them to the dropdown using the logic as the `taxonomy` field

**My attempt at getting my post type**

```
// Get posts in desired category
$posts = array();
$args = array(
            'post_type'      => 'post_type_i_want',
            'orderby'        => 'id',
            'posts_per_page' => -1
        );
$getPosts = get_posts($args);
foreach($getPosts as $post) {
    setup_postdata($post);
    // Yes, I am aware I would *technically* have several times the same value
    // Not getting there yet, so not an issue for me right now
    // Besides, my category currently has but 1 post
    array_push($getPosts, array(
        'standard' => __( 'Option value', 'cmb2' )
    ));
}
// Add field
$cmb_events->add_field( array (
    'name'      => __('Label','cmb2'),
    'id'        => $prefix . 'enseignant',
    'type'      => 'taxonomy_select',
    'options'   => $teamMembers
));
```

However, I am getting no errors, and no values in my dropdown. I can't seem to get much for querying posts in the official [Documentation](https://github.com/webdevstudios/CMB2/wiki), so I am coming up pretty empty on the subject. Any suggestions?

---

### EDIT

[I have posted an answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/39794244/2748327) which uses [Advanced Custom Fields](https://wordpress.org/plugins/advanced-custom-fields/).

---

### EDIT #2

[Another answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/39813536/2748327) providing a link to the proper page has been provided.

Comment: there are a few things not clear in your q... is the issue with get_posts or adding the extra fields? If the latter you need to provide more info, ie. the hook, the code populating the other variables. If the former, var_dump it. One quick note on your query args, it should be `ID` rather than `id`.

Comment: can you `print_r($hetPosts)` and `print_r($teamMembers)` end of after cmb _events

Answer (score 2):

Its seems your are assigning $teamMembers to options ,and but it not defined and don't have any values assigned.

```
// Get posts in desired category
$posts = array();
$args = array(
        'post_type'      => 'post_type_i_want',
        'orderby'        => 'id',
        'posts_per_page' => -1
    );
$getPosts = get_posts($args);
foreach($getPosts as $post) {
    setup_postdata($post);
    // Yes, I am aware I would *technically* have several times the same value
    // Not getting there yet, so not an issue for me right now
    // Besides, my category currently has but 1 post
    array_push($posts, array(
    'standard' => __( 'Option value', 'cmb2' )
));
}
// Add field
$cmb_events->add_field( array (
    'name'      => __('Label','cmb2'),
    'id'        => $prefix . 'enseignant',
    'type'      => 'taxonomy_select',
    'options'   => $posts
));
```

Try this code ,Hope you will get the options values

Answer (score 2):

There is a demonstration for this in the wiki. https://github.com/WebDevStudios/CMB2/wiki/Adding-your-own-field-types#example-2-posts-or-other-post_type-dropdown-store-post_id

---

#### Edit

As explained in documentation :

*For the times when you need to relate one post to another, this comes in handy.*

*Like the terms field above, we would pass an array of posts to the `select` field type. First we'll create a function to pull back an array of post options:*

```
/**
 * Gets a number of posts and displays them as options
 * @param  array $query_args Optional. Overrides defaults.
 * @return array             An array of options that matches the CMB2 options array
 */
function cmb2_get_post_options( $query_args ) {

    $args = wp_parse_args( $query_args, array(
        'post_type'   => 'post',
        'numberposts' => 10,
    ) );

    $posts = get_posts( $args );

    $post_options = array();
    if ( $posts ) {
        foreach ( $posts as $post ) {
          $post_options[ $post->ID ] = $post->post_title;
        }
    }

    return $post_options;
}

/**
 * Gets 5 posts for your_post_type and displays them as options
 * @return array An array of options that matches the CMB2 options array
 */
function cmb2_get_your_post_type_post_options() {
    return cmb2_get_post_options( array( 'post_type' => 'your_post_type', 'numberposts' => 5 ) );
}
```

*Then, when creating our field, we would add the `multicheck` type and use `cmb2_get_your_post_type_post_options` as a callback function to the `options_cb` field parameter. Using the callback this way ensures that the query ONLY happens when the field is called (rather than on every page-load).*

```
$cmb_demo->add_field( array(
    'name'       => __( 'Select your_post_type Posts', 'cmb2' ),
    'desc'       => __( 'field description (optional)', 'cmb2' ),
    'id'         => $prefix . 'post_multicheckbox',
    'type'       => 'multicheck',
    'options_cb' => 'cmb2_get_your_post_type_post_options',
) );
```

***Alternatively**, you could use the `multicheck`, or `radio` field types as well.*

*If you're looking for a similar solution for saving a term_id (or term_ids), [read about it on the Tips & Tricks page.](https://github.com/WebDevStudios/CMB2/wiki/Tips-&-Tricks#a-dropdown-for-taxonomy-terms-which-does-not-set-the-term-on-the-post)*

Comment: I've allowed myself to add a quote to the mentioned quote, both to offer a more complete answer for people who will view this question in the future. Given that this does answer the question, but that I have found a work around, I will simply upvote, rather than mark as the proper answer. Thank you for this gem, though!

Answer (score 0):

Ah! At last! I have found a way to go around the custom programming -- I have set up [Advanced Custom Fields](https://wordpress.org/plugins/advanced-custom-fields/) and added a "post_object" type where I set my category to the post type I want.

However, I will give [bonus points to Mohamed Nizar](https://stackoverflow.com/a/39782790/2748327) for his answer which pointed out that $teamMembers wasn't defined, thus allowing for a proper query result.